# Cisco AnyConnect profile using IPsec

Tags: vpn, cisco, anyconnect

The AnyConnect vpn always tries to use SSL connection instead of **IPsec** even if it is set in the profile.

I have an instance of anyconnect running with some vpn (`other.vpn`) (not IPsec), which works perfectly and
I tried to set up an additional profile (`my.server`) for anycconect where `PrimaryProtocol` was set to `IPsec`.
I expected that for my new connection, anyconnect would use IPsec, but in my vpn server (fortigate 60f), in the CLI, I can see that it tries to connect using port 443.
The anyconnectclient shows the following message: "The service provider in your current location is restricting access to the internet. You need to log on with the service provider...".

On the same machine, I've set up the same connection for `my.server` with **vpnc** and it works perfectly, so nothing wrong with my vpn server configuration.

The new, not-working profile, located under /opt/cisco/anyconnect/profile looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnyConnectProfile xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/ AnyConnectProfile.xsd">
    <ServerList>
        <HostEntry>
            <HostName>my.server</HostName>
            <HostAddress>my.server</HostAddress>
            <PrimaryProtocol>IPsec</PrimaryProtocol>
            <UserGroup>MyUserGroup</UserGroup>
        </HostEntry>
    </ServerList>
</AnyConnectProfile>
```

and the profile for the connection to a different vpn server, that I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnyConnectProfile xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/encoding/ AnyConnectProfile.xsd">
    <ClientInitialization>
        <UseStartBeforeLogon UserControllable="true">false</UseStartBeforeLogon>
        <AutomaticCertSelection UserControllable="true">false</AutomaticCertSelection>
        <ShowPreConnectMessage>false</ShowPreConnectMessage>
        <CertificateStore>All</CertificateStore>
        <CertificateStoreMac>All</CertificateStoreMac>
        <CertificateStoreOverride>false</CertificateStoreOverride>
        <ProxySettings>Native</ProxySettings>
        <AllowLocalProxyConnections>true</AllowLocalProxyConnections>
        <AuthenticationTimeout>12</AuthenticationTimeout>
        <AutoConnectOnStart UserControllable="true">false</AutoConnectOnStart>
        <MinimizeOnConnect UserControllable="true">true</MinimizeOnConnect>
        <LocalLanAccess UserControllable="true">true</LocalLanAccess>
        <DisableCaptivePortalDetection UserControllable="true">false</DisableCaptivePortalDetection>
        <ClearSmartcardPin UserControllable="false">true</ClearSmartcardPin>
        <IPProtocolSupport>IPv4,IPv6</IPProtocolSupport>
        <AutoReconnect UserControllable="false">true
            <AutoReconnectBehavior UserControllable="false">ReconnectAfterResume</AutoReconnectBehavior>
        </AutoReconnect>
        <SuspendOnConnectedStandby>false</SuspendOnConnectedStandby>
        <AutoUpdate UserControllable="false">true</AutoUpdate>
        <RSASecurIDIntegration UserControllable="false">Automatic</RSASecurIDIntegration>
        <WindowsLogonEnforcement>SingleLocalLogon</WindowsLogonEnforcement>
        <LinuxLogonEnforcement>SingleLocalLogon</LinuxLogonEnforcement>
        <WindowsVPNEstablishment>LocalUsersOnly</WindowsVPNEstablishment>
        <LinuxVPNEstablishment>LocalUsersOnly</LinuxVPNEstablishment>
        <AutomaticVPNPolicy>false</AutomaticVPNPolicy>
        <PPPExclusion UserControllable="false">Disable
            <PPPExclusionServerIP UserControllable="false"></PPPExclusionServerIP>
        </PPPExclusion>
        <EnableScripting UserControllable="false">false</EnableScripting>
        <EnableAutomaticServerSelection UserControllable="false">false
            <AutoServerSelectionImprovement>20</AutoServerSelectionImprovement>
            <AutoServerSelectionSuspendTime>4</AutoServerSelectionSuspendTime>
        </EnableAutomaticServerSelection>
        <RetainVpnOnLogoff>false
        </RetainVpnOnLogoff>
        <CaptivePortalRemediationBrowserFailover>false</CaptivePortalRemediationBrowserFailover>
        <AllowManualHostInput>true</AllowManualHostInput>
    </ClientInitialization>
    <ServerList>
        <HostEntry>
            <HostName>other.vpn</HostName>
            <HostAddress>other.vpn</HostAddress>
            <MobileHostEntryInfo>
                <CertificatePolicy>Auto</CertificatePolicy>
                <ConnectOnDemand>false</ConnectOnDemand>
                <ActivateOnImport>false</ActivateOnImport>
            </MobileHostEntryInfo>
        </HostEntry>
    </ServerList>
</AnyConnectProfile>
```

I also tried to remove temporarily the `other.vpn`-connection and restarted vpnagent to see if it had some impact, but same result.

Any help is highly appreciated.